# Why this following code prints x values as 1 and y values as 10

Tags: node.js

```
    var y;

function modify(x) {

    var z = 5;
    x += 2;
    y += x + z

}

var x = 1,
    y = 2,
    z = 3
modify(x)
```

Above snippet result is x=1,y=10,z=3 Please explain this code. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the modify function, "x" is in the scope of modify, and is not going to use the x in the global scope. In addition, primitive types, such as numbers, are passed by value instead of reference. Therefore, x is always going to remain 1.

Also in the modify function, you are declaring a new variable of z in the scope of the modify function, so just like x, z is going to remain as 3.

Since y isn't declared in the function, it's going to use the global scope, so that's the only one that's going to change. In this case it's 2 + ((1 + 2) + 5), which is how you get 10.